# std::remove_reference explained?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I saw possible implementations for [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) as below

```
template< class T > struct remove_reference      {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_reference<T&>  {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_reference<T&&> {typedef T type;};
```

Why is it that there are specializations for `lvalue` and `rvalue reference`? Won't the general template itself be sufficient and remove the reference? I'm confused here because in the `T&` or `T&&` specialization if I try to use `::type` I should still get `T&` or `T&&` respectively right?

Could you explain how, why we cast to `remove_reference<t>::type&&` in move? (is it because that the parameter is named so it will be treated as an lvalue inside the move function?).

Also, could you point out a way whereby I can find out and print what the type is? for e.g if its an `rvalue` of type `int` then I should be able to print out that `int&&` was passed? (I've been using `std::is_same` to check but manually.)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is a **VERY** good question!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> why is it that there are specializations for lvalue and rvalue reference?

If only the primary template existed, then doing:

```
remove_reference<int&>::type
```

Would give you:

```
int&
```

And doing:

```
remove_reference<int&&>::type
```

Would give you:

```
int&&
```

Which is not what you want. The specializations for lvalue references and rvalue references allow stripping the `&` and the `&&`, respectively, from the type argument you pass.

For instance, if you are doing:

```
remove_reference<int&&>
```

The type `int&&` will match the pattern specified by the `T&&` specialization, with `T` being `int`. Since the specialization defines the type alias `type` to be `T` (in this case, `int`), doing:

```
remove_reference<int&&>::type
```

Will give you `int`.

> could you explain how, why we cast to `remove_reference<t>::type&&` in `move`?

That's because if `move()` were defined as follows:

```
    template<typename T>
    T&& move(T&& t) { ... }
//  ^^^
//  Resolves to X& if T is X& (which is the case if the input has type X
//  and is an lvalue)
```

Then the return type will be `X&` if the argument of `move()` is an lvalue of type `X` (that's how so-called "universal references"). We want to make sure that the return type is *always* an rvalue reference.

The purpose of `move()` is to give you back an rvalue, no matter what you pass in input. Since a function call for a function whose return type is an rvalue reference is an rvalue, we really want `move()` to always return an rvalue reference.

That's why we do `remove_reference<T>::type&&`, because appending `&&` to a non-reference type is always guaranteed to yield an rvalue reference type.

> Also could you point out a way whereby I can find out and print what the type is?

I'm not sure what you mean by "print" here. There is no portable way I know of converting the name of a type to a string (no matter how you obtain that type).

If your goal is to make sure that an rvalue was passed, on the other hand, you could use a static assertion like so:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void foo(T&&)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_reference<T>::value, "Error: lvalue was passed!");
    // ...
}
```

Which relies on the fact that when an lvalue of type `X` is being passed, `T` will be deduced to be `X&`.

You could also use an equivalent SFINAE-constraint, if you only want to produce a substitution failure:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_reference<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void foo(T&&)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: then why is the specialization for `T&&`? general template can handle this right?

Comment: @Koushik: You mean the primary template? Well, if only the primary template existed, then `remove_reference<int&&>::type` would give you back `int&&`

Comment: yes correction made. in the specializations also we get the same right? for `T&&` we get `T&&` for `::type` right?

Comment: @Koushik: No, we get `T`, because the specialization matches the pattern `T&&`, so if you pass (say) `int&&` and match it with `T&&`, your `T` must be just `int`

Comment: oh ok ok ok...:-) i'm so dumb. now everything is crystal clear. i was under the impressin that for `T&&` specialization the `T` in the typedef is still `T&&`. but i'm wrong.it is `T` . Thanks a lot:-)

Comment: @Koushik: You're not dumb, it's just a matter of practice ;) Getting the hang of these things is not that simple

Comment: ah yes i need to practice a lot. These type of specializations are applicable to template functions also?

Comment: @Koushik: Yes and no. Explicit specializations are allowed, partial specializations are not. And even when it is allowed, specializing function templates is usually considered a bad idea, because it does not always do what you think. Functions can be *overloaded* on the other hand, and function overloaded is considered to be a superior technique. It can solve most of the problems (sometimes using a technique called "tag dispatch"), so the situations that *really* call for function template specialization are rare. I would advise using overloading as much as you can for function templates

Comment: ah the SFINAE constraint looks more juicy. i think it will be better to use that and yes i will look at overloads henceforth. Thanks for all your help.:-)

Comment: It is actually not standard compliant to have a void pointer as a non type template parameter.  You should use an anonymous `typename = std::enable_if_t<...>` instead

Comment: Won't `std::is_reference<T>::value` be true for rvalues too?

Comment: @baruch Search for "Forwarding References" on Google. It is a special case in order to deal with the difference between `lvalue` and `rvalue`.

Comment: And there is a good post on this topic: [Perfect Forwarding](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

When you treat some type as template parameter, compiler searches for the most "specialized" specialization. If you pass a int&& to this template, compiler use `remove_reference<T&&>` version. General specialization don't give you what you want - if you pass `int&&` to general specialiation, type will be `int&&`

If you want to print type, use `typeid(some_type).name()`

Comment: i used typeid but in gcc it was something awkward. i think i have to use some filter right? other than typeid is there any compile time stuff? so that i can use with static_assert?

Comment: @Koushik: Could you please clarify that part of the question? Do you want to get a string which contains the name of the type, or do you just want to make sure an rvalue reference was passed?

Comment: @AndyProwl it will be good to get the string during debug phase and yes i want to make sure only rvalue was passed andy. if i can get this during compile time then its most helpful.

Comment: @Koushik: OK, I edited my answer. There is no portable way of getting the name of a type, though (to some extent this is possible though: you can google for "C++ pretty print")

Comment: You can run `c++filt -t` to unmangle gcc's `typeid()::name()` output. For example, `c++filt -t FRSt8ios_baseS0_E` returns `std::ios_base& (std::ios_base&)` - which is the type of the function `std::boolalpha`.